# Beobachten + preposition? Auf? bei?

Tags: grammar, preposition

I've noticed the most common preposition used with *achten* is *auf*. However today I found a sentence that uses the preposition *bei*:

> *Wenn die Neuronen nicht funktionieren, ist es schwer zu lügen. Das wurde z.B. bei autistischen Kindern beobachtet*.

Is it grammatically possible to use *auf* in this sentence. If not, why? Is perhaps the meaning of *bei* in this sentence *among*?

Comment: Are you asking about "achten" or "beobachten"... title says one thing, the first sentence another, the example one again.

Comment: I'm asking about beobachten. I used the achten+auf just to know if it is the same with beobachten since both of these have the "main verb" achten.

Comment: the prepositions vary from prefix to prefix. There are no paralels there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb `beobachten` doesn't really take a preposition, so using a preposition like `auf` would be incorrect. It's always

> jmdn./etw. beobachten

In this case the `bei` preposition doesn't have too much to do with the verb. This usage of `bei` can be seen with all kinds of verbs. *Among* could be a good translation. I'd say a fair translation, for this specific usage of bei, would be:

> *In the case* of autistic children

You could use this `bei` in call kinds of situations and it's very useful. A good example would be a simple exchange among friends:

> -Alles klar?
>
> -Ja, bei dir?

Also, like Sandra mentioned, there's a tiny mistake in the original statement. It should be `beobachtet`, since that's the proper conjugation for the passive voice

Comment: To elaborate, the object of *beobachten* here is *Das*. Instead of *bei Kindern* other additions are thinkable, e.g. *im Rahmen einer Studie* or *schon im letzten Jahrhundert*.

Answer (score 1):

The words "beobachten" und "achten" have slightly different meanings and therefore use different prepositions

> auf etwas achten = to pay attention to sth.
>   bei jemandem beobachten = to monitor, to keep an eye on

Comment: Well, clinch made a point saying that *bei* has not much to do with the verb. That's true, as you can say "bei jemandem auf etwas achten".

Answer (score 1):

> Achten auf: To pay attention TO.
>
> Beobachten: To observe (no preposition).
>
> Das wurde bei autistischen Kindern beobachtet. That was BY the autistic children observed. (By refers to the children, and not to beobachten.)

Comment: The translation is wrong. The German idiom *beobachtet bei* translates to the English idiom *observed with*. The English passive construction *observed by* translates to the German passive construction *beobachtet von/durch*.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *beobachten* is transitive *(etw. beobachten)*. For an example consider your question. There it means *to observe*.

Comment: It is ambitransitive... that is,it can be used without object, too.

Comment: @Emanuel, ok, I was not aware of that distinction.